# Mount ISO for MDT deployment?

Tags: mount, iso, mdt-2010

I installed MDT 2010 and worked out how to deploy win7.

Now I want to be able to boot to a Acronis-Boot-CD over the network. (without having to insert the cd)

Is this possible?
I have got the ISO-File of Acronis.
How could I "mount" this to be able to boot to it in Litetouch?

Answer (score 1):

Not to sure what you're trying to do with the Acronis Boot CD. Are you wanting to mount it inside of WinPE? Any reason why? Might be easier to take those tools out of the boot disc and place them inside your WinPE environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, kind of. Follow the directions here. http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/WDSLINUX

It will take some tinkering but It is possible in most cases to boot an ISO over PXE using WDS.